# Posting on Facebook - error - The user must be an administrator of the page in order to impersonate it

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, posting

I'm posting automatically news from web site to FaceBook: 
www.rybnik.com.pl -> rybnikcompl

It worked fine for a few months.

But 2 days ago I noticed error:

> "The user must be an administrator of the page in order to impersonate it."

As I know nothing changed in user, application rights, access token, etc.

The sending script (in PHP) is also fine - it is still sends post from another sites to FaceBook (of course with another ids and tokens).

The strange thing I saw is that on the page:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
name of my application disappeared from list "Get Token" (but still exist on list "Application: Graph API Explorer" on the same page).

So I (probably) can't generate proper User Access Token.

Application permissions: user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, email, manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile

Have you some suggestion what is wrong?
How to fix it?

/PiotrW

Comment: why all those permission? you only need manage_pages and puglish_pages to post on a page you own...

Comment: I might try to remove some of them, but application worked with that. And, as I know, publish_actions is also required

Comment: you should only use permissions you need. and you do NOT need publish_actions to post to a page (as page). publish_actions is to post as user.

Comment: anyway, see if the app shows up here: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

Comment: "None of your apps are restricted."

Comment: if the app does not show up in the list in the api explorer, you could file a bug. it does sound like one.

Comment: Thanks for comment.
I solved the problem.
Another administrator remove the user who publish news from Admin Role.
Give the role again was the solution.

Topic to close.