# The user must be an administrator of the page in order to impersonate it

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting this error:
`FacebookResponseException in FacebookResponseException.php line 106:
The user must be an administrator of the page in order to impersonate it.`

The admin has been changed and the website has a new developer now (me). The feed worked before and I have no idea what else to try... This is everything that has changed or I did to the code:

1. I am the administrator (one of 4) of the facebook page with my personal profile.
2. And I am also the owner of the facebook developers app.
3. I have only changed the .env credentials (the faceboook_app_id and facebook_app_secret).

Any ideas on what could fix this?
I found this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356829/posting-on-facebook-error-the-user-must-be-an-administrator-of-the-page-in-o), but I only need to get some of the last posts and the feed, so I dont need to post to the page (like the other question).

Comment: If you change the secret and the key, you need to update that info on your laravel code

Comment: So you are using a page access token? If the page admin is removed, it invalidates any page access tokens they granted as well. So you need to grant the necessary permission to your app, and then generate a new page access token.

Comment: @CBroe I am not sure on how to generate a new access token, and where to specify it.. Is that all done on the facebook developers site of in the source code of my laravel?

Comment: That depends on what “your laravel” actually does.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the sammyk package was installed with composer, in the config folder the variables are pulled from the .env (which i updated) and this is the function (did not write this myself) https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/acf88d6d2e85d843dede35d684c82767